# Does the DTrace pid provider only work for debug mode compiled programs?

Tags: dtrace

I want to use DTrace to track FFI usage in a wide range of programs.

DTrace is designed to work in production environments, but most software is compiled and distributed with compiler optimisations.

Do these optimisations prevent using the `pid` provider to track the `entry` and `return` probes?

E.g.

- `pid$target::example_ffi_fn_x:entry`
- `pid$target::example_ffi_fn_x:return`

http://dtrace.org/guide/dtrace-ebook.pdf#page=291

> When the compiler inlines a function, the pid provider’s probe does
>   not fire. To **avoid inlining a function at compile time**, consult the
>   documentation for your compiler.

Does this mean that you can only use DTrace on programs that publish USDT probes or are compiled in debug mode (without optimisations)?

Is there another way to track FFI usage in programs where I do not have the original source code?

Answer (score 2):

Compiler optimizations don't impede DTrace's ability to trace functions for the most part. Yes, aggressive (or explicit) inlining will render a function invisible, but that's mercifully uncommon. A more typical challenge in binaries is the lack of symbolic information that lets you find the functions you might be interested in.

I'm pretty sure I documented this, but I can't find it--it's certainly in the code: the pid provider lets you specify instruction addresses within a process' address space. Now, it seems to be subtly broken in macOS 10.15.2 (where I'm testing it out), but it would look something like this: `dtrace -n 'pid11118::-:0x103c87a19'`